# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element' - Selenium driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am in the process of rewriting this old pyton script (https://github.com/muvvasandeep/BuGL/blob/master/Scripts/DataExtraction.py) which used older version of Selenium. The aim of this script is to extract open and closed issues from open source projects form github. I am new to both python and Selenium. I am having hard time rewriting several things inside it. Currently I am struggling to get this working:

```
repo_closed_url = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]').find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'h4')]
```

the above should get all closed issues link from a github page and store it in the repo_closed_url array. But i am getting the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element' error. Please help.

Comment: This error occurs because you're trying to use .find_element for a list. try to get data type of driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this code line worked ever.
It uses `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]')` method then trying to apply `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'h4')` on the output of previous method.
But `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]')` returns a **list** of web element objects. While `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'h4')` can be applied on `webdriver` or `webelement` object only, not on a list of objects.
That code can be refactored as mentioned by dm2

```py
repo_closed_url = [link.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'h4').get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]')]
```

In this case `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]')` output is a list of web element objects, you are performing inline iteration on this list with `for link in (output of)(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]'))` and then appying `.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'h4').get_attribute('href')` on each `link` element in the previously received list of links

Comment: Thanks you man! I am not sure the person who wrote the initial script deliberately did mistakes but anyway, your suggestion worked! I will ask few more doubts here in the comment section and it will be really great if you could help me with that as well. Thanks again!

Comment: The above code gets the first closed issue link all the time However I want to get links of all the closed issues in each page. - https://github.com/moodle/moodle/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed 

Is it possible to do that? The array only stores 1 URL.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to go now. Will be back tomorrow

Comment: Hi! I am still trying to get the links of all the closed issues in this page. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I am going by page by page so just fixing the above code itself will be fine.

Comment: I don't know. Please open a new question for that so all the users will see it in their feed, not just me. We will try to help there

Comment: just opened one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75301196/getting-list-of-all-the-urls-in-a-closed-issue-page-in-github-using-selenium

Comment: Great. I already answered. Please let me know if it worked. Now I had some time, I'm sorry for the previous time when I had to go.

Answer (score 1):

`find_elements` returns a list, and a list doesn't have a method `find_element` (as per your error message).

You could move the `find_element` method to `link`:

```
repo_closed_url = [link.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'h4').get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]')]
```

Which seems more of what you're trying to do, instead of iterating over a single element, you iterate over a list of elements from the `find_elements` method.

Comment: The above code gets the first closed issue link all the time However I want to get links of all the closed issues in each page. - github.com/moodle/moodle/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed Is it possible to do that? The array only stores 1 URL