# Getting list of all the URLs in a Closed Issue page in GitHub using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to store the links of all the closed issues from a GitHub  (https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) project using Selenium. I use the code below:

```
repo_closed_url = [link.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'h4').get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@aria-label="Issues"]')]
```

However, the above code only returns the first URL. How can I get all the URLs in that page? I iterate through all the pages. So just getting the links from the first page is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. This should work:

```py
repo_closed_url = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@aria-label='Issues']//a[contains(@class,'h4')]")]
```

Here `//div[@aria-label='Issues']//a[contains(@class,'h4')]` XPath locates directly all the desired title elements on the page.
Then the rest of the code in the line is iterating over the list of returning elements extracting their `href` attributes as I explained in the previous question.

Comment: i tested it and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below XPath expression:

`//div[@aria-label='Issues']//a[contains(@id,'issue')]`

This XPath expression will list all the closed issues in page 1. Just use `.get_attribute('href')` to get the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the links from all the *href* attributes you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='issue_'] a[id^='issue']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'issue_')]//a[starts-with(@id, 'issue')]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3371', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3370', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3369', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3368', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3367', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3365', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3364', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3363', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3356', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3353', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3352', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3351', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3348', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3340', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3338', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3336', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3333', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3329', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3326', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3325', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3324', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3323', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3319', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3314', 'https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3303']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```